# Can't add margin to a button inside a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android

Why would I not be able to add margin to the end of this button?

```
<!--Buttons-->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/arqo_llButtons" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="98dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:background="@color/white" >

    <!--Pay Button-->
    <android.widget.Button android:id="@+id/arqo_btnQuickApplyPayment" style="@style/CustomButtonStyle.Success"
                    android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="60dp" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:enabled="false" android:text="@string/button_pay" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



<style name="CustomButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_height">55dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">332dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/border_button_text</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_border</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomButtonStyle.Success" parent="@style/CustomButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_success</item>
</style>
```

The button here just sits on the very right edge of the constraint layout...

Comment: can u share ur CustomButtonStyle.Success code ??

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo updated

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize your button with a custom style, your custom style should inherit a button's style.
Something like this :

```
<style name="CustomStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">

    <!-- Style your custom button here -->

</style>
```

For more info : [Material Button theming](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#theming-buttons)
[Material3 Button Theming](https://m3.material.io/components/buttons/implementation/android#:%7E:text=%7D-,Theming%20buttons,-Buttons%20support%20Material)

Comment: adding the parent style didn't fix it.  But I think you're warm.  I removed the styling all together from the button and all of a sudden margins starting working.

Comment: If you style the button correctly , the margins will work.

Comment: OK, found the culprit....If I comment this out from the style it works:

<item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>

weird.

Answer (score 0):

Removing this line from the CustomButtonStyle in Styles.xml solved the issue:

```
<item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
```